# Limit post excerpt and post content in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this following snipper :

```
<div class="content">
                            <h2><?php echo $article->post_title ?></h2>
                            <h3><?php echo get_field( 'subtitle', $article->ID ); ?></h3>
                            <p><?php echo display_post_excerpt( $article->post_excerpt, $article->post_content ); ?></p>

                        </div>
```

Here is display_post_excerpt function :

```
function display_post_excerpt( $excerpt, $content ){
    if( $excerpt != '' ){
        $text = $excerpt;
    }else{
        $text = $content;
    }

    $text = strip_tags( $text );

    return $text;
```

}

I want to limit the post excerpt (and also content if posts dont have excerpt). I dont know how should I proceed and also where (in the function.php? the template? I guess I should use something like :

```
if (strlen($text) > 20) {
strlen($text) == 20;
}
```

But as I am a big noob, I am not sure.
Can you help guys?

Answer (score 1):

```
function display_post_excerpt( $excerpt, $content ){
    if( $excerpt != '' ){
        $text = $excerpt;
        if (strlen($text) > 20) {
          $text = substr($text,0,strpos($text,' ',20)) . ' ... <a href="' . get_permalink() . '">[ read more ]</a>'; } ;
         }
         else{
            $text = $content;
         }
    }

    return $text;

}
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work.
What if I want to add the same limit to $content, does that work : 
function display_post_excerpt( $excerpt, $content ){
    if( $excerpt != '' ){
        $text = $excerpt;
        if (strlen($text) > 100) {
          $text = substr($text,0,strpos($text,' ',100)) . ' [...] ';
         }

         else {
            $text = $content;
         if (strlen($text) > 100) {
             $text = substr($text,0,strpos($text,' ',100)) . ' ... ';
          }

         }
    }

    return $text;

}

Answer (score 0):

I think that the better solution is to add to your `functions.php` file below code:

```
function wpt_excerpt_length($length) {
    return 16;
  }
  add_filter('excerpt_length', 'wpt_excerpt_length', 999);
```

You can read more about excerpt here [Function Reference/the excerpt](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt#Control_Excerpt_Length_using_Filters)